# exception performance in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, exception

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which handles exceptions in the typical way.  We try to code against them when we can (check for null, use TryParse, etc), and we do not use them as flow control (i.e. we return false from a method that fails instead of throwing an exception to signify failure).  We have catch-all exception handling in application_error to catch anything that get's up that far.

We have a custom controller factory and when the controller could not be created, we were throwing a WebException with a HTTP 404 error.  Our corporate security team periodically scans our web applications with a McAfee product which hits a website with a bunch of known vurnerable URLs.  Since none of these URLs matched a route, we were throwing hundreds of 404s / minute, and our application slowed down to a crawl.  We quickly took out the code to throw an exception on a 404, however now senior management is concerned about things like "memory leaks" (since that's essentially what slowed the server down... memory saturation), and DOS.

Now I know exceptions are slow.  I've been looking online and most of the guidlines say to just try really really hard to make sure they don't happen because they're slow (especially with deep stacks).  I'm struggling though to determine whether they are THIS bad, or if there's also something wrong with my code.  If exception handling is this bad, wouldn't that lead to a very easy DOS for asp.net based applications?

Any general thoughts would be appreciated.  Right now I'm just trying to get my head around the problem.

Comment: "General thoughts" is not what SO is for - if you show some code, we can provide more useful feedback.

Comment: I've seen lots of topics like this on here.  People asking for thoughts, approaches, suggestions, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask - "general thoughts" sounds more like a discussion than "explain x".

Comment: Probably better for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/